# How to create user defined time table

Tags: tables, pdftex, datetime2

I have to create a three years work plane, but it still only shows me 4 months,

How do I need to do?

```
        \documentclass{article}       
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfgantt}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \newcounter{myWeekNum}
    \stepcounter{myWeekNum}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\myWeek}{\themyWeekNum
        \stepcounter{myWeekNum}
        \ifnum\themyWeekNum=53
        \setcounter{myWeekNum}{2}
        \else\fi
    }
    %
    %%% Begin document

        \setcounter{myWeekNum}{1}
        \ganttset{%
            calendar week text={\myWeek{}}%
        }
        %
        \begin{figure}[h!bt]
            \begin{center}
                \begin{ganttchart}[
                    vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},
                    x unit=.08cm,
                    y unit title=.6cm,
                    y unit chart=.6cm,
                    time slot format=isodate,
                    time slot format/start date=2019-6-01]{2021-12-01}{2022-04-30}
                    \ganttset{bar height=1.6}
                    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name} \\
                    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task 1}{2019-6-01}{2021-12-01}\\
                    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task 2}{2019-6-01}{2021-12-01}\\
                    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task 3}{2019-6-01}{2021-12-01}\\
                    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red}]{Task 4}{2021-12-01}{2022-04-19}
                \end{ganttchart}
            \end{center}
                \caption{Time Plan}
            \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I think you have to change dates here `{2021-12-01}{2022-04-30}`.

Comment: Use `start date=2019-1-01` and `{2019-1-01}{2022-12-31}` for years 2019-2022.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. It is not clear to me what you want.

Since 3 years has 36 months, the width image is *tooooo* long. So a `standalone` will produce a wider pdf.

Here is only a piece from pdf viewer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{myWeekNum}
\stepcounter{myWeekNum}

\newcommand{\myWeek}{\themyWeekNum
    \stepcounter{myWeekNum}
    \ifnum\themyWeekNum=53
    \setcounter{myWeekNum}{2}
    \else\fi
}
\setcounter{myWeekNum}{1}
\ganttset{%
    calendar week text={\myWeek{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},
    x unit=.08cm,
    y unit title=.6cm,
    y unit chart=.6cm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    time slot format/start date=2019-1-01]{2019-1-01}{2022-12-31}
    \ganttset{bar height=.6}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name} \\
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task 1}{2019-6-01}{2021-12-01}\\
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task 2}{2019-6-01}{2021-12-01}\\
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=blue}]{Task 3}{2019-6-01}{2021-12-01}\\
    \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=red}]{Task 4}{2021-12-01}{2022-04-19}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I only want to creat a three years plane in A4 page. can we change the size of the value of width for every month?

Comment: I am not expert and never used this tool. Maybe, take a look at its documentation at https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt

Comment: is there other package to do such works?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: no, I have to say "thank you very much"

Comment: You are welcome. Usually, almost all packages come with good documentation.